# How to override spring beans with Java config

Tags: java, spring, overriding, config, javabeans

I encountered this issue when I'm trying to override the RibbonRoutingFilter bean defined in spring zuul. To emphasis, I'm doing an override, not just creating a bean of the same type. So end of the day, I want the "ribbonRoutingFilter" bean from zuul not registered at all.

So I have my own implementation. First thing I tried, I used the @component annotation and autowire the dependencies. Added a breakpoint in the constructor, and it ended up never being called. So I realize my definition must be loaded earlier than zuul's. So I created a configuration class with @Configuration annotation and `@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)`, and use a @Bean annotation to instantiate my class there. Still, my method is always loaded earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out there's certain order Spring is following when loading configuration classes definitions and that is where overrides happen. Class org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser has the detailed logic in method doProcessConfigurationClass(). I'll put my simplified summarization or the ordering rule here:

1. if you application class(where main() method is defined) has any classes defined in it, they are parsed and definition inside them are registered first
2. then it will registered Beans defined as @component and defined in @Configuration class
3. then it will add definitions introduced by @Import
4. then it will add definitions introduced by @ImportResource
5. then add definitions from @bean methods inside the application class
6. then from default methods on interfaces( I think it's java 8)
7. then try to do the same steps above for any parent classes you application class has extended.

This explained why my override was not working. It's because all I have been trying is in step 2. But zuul defined the bean by a @Import which is step 3.

So to solve my problem, I added a @Bean annotated method to my application class there and do the instanciation and the override just happend as expected.

The above summarization might not be accurate, it just give you an idea about what could have failed your override. You'd better debug the ConfigurationClassParser when you are trying your specific use case.

Comment: Please follow Stack Overflow's Q&A format when answering your own questions. This is not an answer.